# Neo4j Facet Fields like Solr

Tags: neo4j, faceted-search, gremlin

I'm using Neo4j in a community e-commerce built in PHP and using the REST interface.

I need to get all categories related to the search results like Amazon. This feature is available in other engines like Solr (another implementation of Lucene) as [**Faceted Search**](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0-BETA/facet/org/apache/lucene/facet/doc-files/userguide.html)

How can I do a **Faceted Search** in Neo4j? or What's the best way (performance grade) to recreate this feature?

All required modules related to this feature are excluded from the core package of neo4j. I want to know if someone try to do something like this without transverse all nodes in the graph, grab some properties, and make a groupCount of this values. If we have 200k nodes, the transverse took 10sec to only get the categories.

This is my Gremlin approach.

```
(new Neo4jVertexSequence(
    g.getRawGraph().index().forNodes('products').query(
        new org.neo4j.index.lucene.QueryContext('category:?')
    ), g
))._().groupBy{it.category}.cap.next();
```

Results in 90 rows and took 54 seconds.

```
Books = 12002
Movies_Music_Games = 19233
Electronics_Computers = 60540
Home_Garden_Tools = 9123
Grocery_Health_Beauty = 15643
Toys_Kids_Baby = 15099
Clothing_Shoes_Jewelry = 12543
Sports_Outdoors = 10342
Automotive_Industrial = 9638
... (more rows)
```

Of course, I can't put this results in cache, because, this is for "non input search". If the user makes a query like "Iphone", the query looks like

```
(new Neo4jVertexSequence(
    g.getRawGraph().index().forNodes('products').query(
        new org.neo4j.index.lucene.QueryContext('search:"iphone" AND category:?')
    ), g
))._().groupBy{it.category}.cap.next();
```

Comment: Nothing yet?? Neo4j developers???

Answer (score 0):

What about your domain model? Did you just put everything in the index? Usually you would model your categories as nodes and have your products being related to the category nodes.

```
(product)-[:HAS_CATEGORY]->(category)<-[:IS_CATEGORY]-(categories)
```

In your query you would just traverse this little tree and count the relationships of type :HAS_CATEGORY starting from each category node.

```
start categories=node(x)
match (product)-[:HAS_CATEGORY]->(category)<-[:IS_CATEGORY]-(categories)
return category.name, count(*)
```

Comment: Hi Michael, Im' glad to hear for someone of neo4j team. I tried your solution but I got the same results in matter of time. Finally the whole graph need to be transversed